# Cannot Programmatically Switch Storyboards

Tags: swift, storyboard

I'm attempting to switch storyboards when a button only if a condition (The textfield not being empty) is met. I found this piece of code as an answer to a similar question, and it doesn't seem to be working. My program crashes with "'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'Avatar Controller''"

I'm not completely sure as to where to find the view controller identifies, or whether or not I have to add '.storyboard' at the end of the storyboard name.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Avatar", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Avatar Controller")
        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be happening for 2 reasons.

**1)** Because in your `Avatar.storyboard` you are referencing a view controller with the id `Avatar Controller` but you have not set that value on any of the view controllers in the storyboard file. Go into your `Avatar.storyboard`, click on the view controller you want to show and go to this panel:

[image]

Make sure that the `Storyboard ID` for your `viewController` matches what value you use in `storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Avatar Controller")`

**2)** Because you are not providing a `bundle` when you are loading your storyboard. You are calling this

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Avatar", bundle: nil);
```

but because you specify `bundle` as `nil` it doesn't know where to look for the `Avatar.storyboard` file. To fix it, specify `bundle` as `Bundle.main`:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Avatar", bundle: Bundle.main);
```

Comment: I just checked that and it is set as 'Avatar Controller', but I'm getting the same error. I retyped it and ran it again just to be sure and it didn't help anything

Comment: fixed it. you weren't specifying a bundle so it didnt know where to look for your storyboard file

Comment: That seemed to have fixed that error, but now I'm getting *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FInal_Project.User_Info NameInputEditingDidEnd:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fababd1b090'

Comment: what is the code @ the line where the error is being thrown

Comment: I'm relatively new to swift so I have no idea as to how I'd figure that out

Comment: I'm assuming you have a navigation controller setup correctly in your `Avatar.storyboard` file

Comment: I do, though that was done by another developer, so I'm not overly familiar with it

Comment: hmm. The `Unrecognized selector` error is fairly common and not very descriptive so I would probably need to see the entire project to be of any further help

Comment: Well I'm not going to ask you to go through all that, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To make it works, `Use Storyboard ID` has to be checked

[image]

Comment: I've checked that and run it and I'm still getting the same error